# responsive design : fancybox thumbnail gallery , resize and place images in the center of the wrapper both vertically and horizontally

Tags: css, html, image, responsive-design, fancybox

*I know such questions are galore in SO but I do not find a single solution to meet my need fully.*

I am using [fancybox jQuery plugin](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) to create a thumbnail gallery ( non-responsive version : [here](http://demo.lumierebd.com/)- gallery is on the right side ) of images and slideshow as well.

The issue is with the thumbnail gallery - images of varying aspect ratios are uploaded and shown in the thumbnail gallery. The wrapper element (`.project_gallery a` - inline anchor has been made to display as `block`) for each image has the dimension 195x195px;

I want the images to stretch to the  full of the `div` and be centered both vertically and horizontally.

***In case you need any explanation of the last sentence above***, I provide it below:

If the uploaded image has its width smaller then the height, the width should be set to fill the  wrapper element fully in the  horizontal direction. Even when the image width is resized to be equal to that of  the wrapper, image height may not still fill the full height of the wrapper. So the image  width still needs to be enlarged **maintaining the aspect ratio**.  At a certain enlargement point, the image height fits the full wrapper height but the image width is then larger than the wrapper width. So the image needs to be placed in center of the wrapper in the horizontal direction. And the left and right side of the image may get cropped i.e: made invisible. The reverse thing should take place if we interchange the height and width of the image in the just-mentioned explanation.

And all those stuff I need to to do in a responsive design way.

**EDIT**:
HTML mark-up for the image gallery is below.The `a` element will be many as this is the wrapper of the image and .many images will be there.

```
<div class="project_gallery">

 <a class="fancybox" href="some_href_here" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Project"><img src="assets/img/projects/img_name "   class="inline_block"  alt="image project"/></a>
 ...
</div>
```

**EDIT2** : The responsive version being devloped is [here](http://demo2.lumierebd.com/)  now.

**EDIT 3 :**  *In case you do not like to look into any specific site, you can **just consider the full question as below** :*

Responsive design thumbnail gallery :   how to  resize and place images with randomly varying aspect ratios in the center of the same sized wrapper `div`s (`img_wrapper`) both vertically and horizontally   leaving no part of the wrapper  unused ? The HTML markup and a bit `CSS` is below:

HTML:

```
    <div id="gallery">

    <div class="img_wrapper"><img src="..." alt="img"/></div> 

    //the above line will repeat as many images as are there.

    </div><!-- end of id gallery-->
```

CSS:

```
<style>
#gallery{
width:70%
}

.img_wrapper{

width:25%;
float:left;
}
</style>
```

Comment: and what is the question?

Comment: @jfk, `And all those stuff I need to to do in a responsive design way.` : pretty clear question - how to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps get you started:

**CSS**

```
.fancybox img.inline_block{
 margin-left:0 !important;
}


.project_gallery a{
 width:100%;
}

.project_right img:first-child{
 margin-left:0;
}

.project_gallery a{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

It's possible you might need to add !important or extra selectors to some of these rules so that they will take precidence and overule the exiting defaults.

Regarding the behaviour you want for the background image filling the full div, I think the existing background-image:cover; setting should do what you want. If it doesn't, start by checking that your images are large enough to fill the div.

You mention that you want to do this is responsive way. Your page design doesn't appear to be responsive, for example the image in the top slider is hard coded at 1050px so this would prevent the page from collapsing in a responsive manner. Unless you moved from your existing fancy box plugin to something like a lightbox, I think it could be a challenge to get your existing gallery to be responsive.

Good luck!

Comment: 1)`If it doesn't, start by checking that your images are large enough to fill the div. ` - I even added an explanation to clarify that images are not always large enough to fill the `div` fully.  2) `You mention that you want to do this is responsive way.` - in Op I mentioned the URL to be for the non-RD version.3) ` Unless you moved from your existing fancy box plugin to something like a lightbox, I think it could be a challenge to get your existing gallery to be responsive.` - I think fancybox is the RD version of lightbox. Url to the script you recommend please.

Comment: I added `EDIT2`.And the code you pasted did not work either. 1) It has redundancy ( `.project_gallery a` appears twice). 2)If the width of  `project_gallery a` is 100%, then the wrapper of a single images covers the full width.

Comment: Hi @IstiaqueAhmed , I'm sorry but I think I misunderstood your question. Not sure if I can help, it's difficult for me to troubleshoot remotely.

Comment: ,` Have a look at the  `EDIT3` I added.

Comment: HI @IstiaqueAhmed, seems to work well for me. The only small issue I notice is that if you have zoomed in to an image, then when you use the arrows to navigate forward or back to view other images there's a brief flash where you see the thumbnail sized image before it refreshes to a full sized image again. Not sure why.